# Create a MethodCallExpression for a sub property

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

In have a working example for a simplified scenario:

```cs
//find all tasks with History item with id equals 117992
var exprString = "Id = 117992"; 

var innerLambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(typeof(History), typeof(bool), exprString);

var resultCallExpression = Expression.Call(
   typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new[] { typeof(History) },
   Expression.Property(givenTaskExpression, "Histories"), innerLambda
);
```

[image]

However I am not able to modify the example to give me a filter expression based on a property which is one level below.

Please check out the given diagram. I have a given expression of type "Task" (givenTaskExpression) now I would like to generate a resulting expression which uses a filter lambda on the chips list.

E.g. give me all tasks which have a case which have a chip with Id = '1234'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```cs
var exprString = "Id = '1234'"; 

var innerLambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(typeof(Chip), typeof(bool), exprString);

var chipsProp = Expression.Property(
   Expression.Property(givenTaskExpression, nameof(Task.Case)),
   nameof(Case.Chips));

var resultCallExpression = Expression.Call(
   typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new[] { typeof(Chip) }
   chipsProp, innerLambda
);
```